# optimize mysql - will index improve in this case?

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Column alo is tinytext (average length: two chars)

My most often query is

```
select * from table where .... order by alo=''
```

Will it be faster when I make an index on alo?

The exactly content of alo does not matter - ordering is only based on the question if alo is empty or not.

Why does it (not) improve speed?

Comment: We don't have enough information to know.  Many things affect the execution speed of a query. Indexes are one of them. We need to know much more if we are to help you.

Comment: `order by alo` will definitively be faster if `alo` is indexed, `order by alo=''` however I doubt. The result of this operation isn't indexed, nothing computed at run time is.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume we are talking only about

```
select * from table where .... order by alo=''
```

Case 1:  No index.  The entire table will always be scanned.

Case 2:  Something in the `WHERE` could use an index.  Then that index may help.

Case 3:  `alo` is not mentioned in the `WHERE`.  Indexing `alo` will not help.  MySQL cannot use an index when the indexed column is hiding in a function.  In this query, `alo=''` is effectively a function call.

Saying `ORDER BY alo` *could* use `INDEX(alo)`.  *And* it would have similar results.  Well, actually `alo=''` sorts blanks after non-blanks.  So you might need `ORDER BY alo DESC` to get the blanks first.  Furthermore, `NULL` values may add another wrinkle.

Meanwhile, there is another optimization... Don't use `TINYTEXT`; instead, use `VARCHAR(..)` with a suitable max.  (The reason has to do with temp tables in complex queries, and may not matter for your query.)  Also, you cannot index any kind of `TEXT` column.